# Excel: How to store an answer in the same cell? How can I accomplish var1+var2= >Store: var2

Tags: excel, google-sheets, var

Title may be vague, let me explain. 
On a TI calculator, I can use variables to create an equation where var2 is used in an equation, and the answer is stored as var2. Is there a way to accomplish this in google sheets (Excel)?

IE: How can I accomplish: var1+var2= >Store: var2

What I'm trying to do in Excel is keep a running total in one cell, with an input in another cell.  (I don't want an incredibly long list of inputs running down the sheet.)

What I have now just results in a cyclical #REF! error:
A1:  (input) 
B1:  =Sum(A1+C1)
C1:  =B1

Comment: You cannot do this with a formula.  You'd need to use VBA in XL or scripting in GS

Comment: You might be able to do this. A1 input B1 =A1 then a2 is another input, b2=a2 +b1. Just copy that formula and you are set.